# Saving to text not showing anything in 'save file type'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi trying to save to a text file from a rich text box with following code and it is not saving and also not giving the option to save file type when the saving prompt comes up:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
    sfd.ShowDialog()
    Dim myPath As String = sfd.FileName
    FileOpen(1, "mypath", OpenMode.Output)
    PrintLine(1, RichTextBox1.Text)
    FileClose(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click    
    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim FileName As String = ""
    Dim mySafeFileName As String = ""         
    Try
        With sfd
            .InitialDirectory = "D:\mypath\data"  ' --> put yor full path here
            .FileName = mySafeFileName
            .Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|"
            If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                FileName = .FileName
                FileOpen(1, FileName , OpenMode.Input)
                PrintLine(1, RichTextBox1.Text)
                FileClose(1)                    
            End If
        End With
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)       
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To default and filter your SaveFileDialog by .txt files you would do the following prior to calling the ShowDialog method.

```
    sfd.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt"
    sfd.DefaultExt = ".txt"
```

You have the name of your variable myPath in quotations in your FileOpen method call.  Remove the quotations for the saving part of this code to work.  As a recommendation, you may want to check into the System.IO.File methods for this.

```
FileOpen(1, myPath, OpenMode.Output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the richtextbox to save the text directly

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click    
Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog       
Try
    With sfd
        .InitialDirectory = "D:\mypath\data"  ' --> put yor full path here
        .Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|"
        If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox1.SaveFile(.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)                
        End If
    End With
Catch ex As System.Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)       
End Try
End Sub
```